# unable to deploy .war file to a local glassfish container using hudson

Tags: hudson, hudson-plugins

ERROR: Publisher hudson.plugins.deploy.DeployPublisher aborted due to exception
org.codehaus.cargo.util.CargoException: The call to deploy returned 1
    at org.codehaus.cargo.container.glassfish.GlassFish2xInstalledLocalDeployer.doDeploy(GlassFish2xInstalledLocalDeployer.java:79)
    at org.codehaus.cargo.container.glassfish.internal.AbstractGlassFishInstalledLocalDeployer.redeploy(AbstractGlassFishInstalledLocalDeployer.java:97)
    at hudson.plugins.deploy.CargoContainerAdapter.deploy(CargoContainerAdapter.java:64)
    at hudson.plugins.deploy.CargoContainerAdapter$1.invoke(CargoContainerAdapter.java:93)
    at hudson.plugins.deploy.CargoContainerAdapter$1.invoke(CargoContainerAdapter.java:77)
    at hudson.FilePath.act(FilePath.java:793)
    at hudson.FilePath.act(FilePath.java:775)
    at hudson.plugins.deploy.CargoContainerAdapter.redeploy(CargoContainerAdapter.java:77)
    at hudson.plugins.deploy.DeployPublisher.perform(DeployPublisher.java:47)
    at hudson.tasks.BuildStepMonitor$3.perform(BuildStepMonitor.java:51)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractRunner.perform(AbstractBuild.java:735)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractRunner.performAllBuildSteps(AbstractBuild.java:713)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractRunner.performAllBuildSteps(AbstractBuild.java:689)
    at hudson.model.Build$RunnerImpl.post2(Build.java:163)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractRunner.post(AbstractBuild.java:655)
    at hudson.model.Run.run(Run.java:1458)
    at hudson.model.FreeStyleBuild.run(FreeStyleBuild.java:44)
    at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:82)
    at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:137)
Finished: FAILURE

Answer (score 0):

> The call to deploy returned 1

Why did the call to deploy return 1?

Answer (score 0):

Btw, glassfish log as such a moment just say:

```
[#|2015-02-27T12:16:32.676+0100|INFO|sun-appserver2.1|javax.enterprise.system.tools.admin|_ThreadID=21;_ThreadName=httpWorkerThread-4848-1;/var/tmp/s1astempCIserver-1206725054/*.ear;|ADM1006:Uploading the file to:[/var/tmp/s1astempCIserver-1206725054/*.ear]|#]

[#|2015-02-27T12:16:35.165+0100|INFO|sun-appserver2.1|javax.enterprise.system.tools.deployment|_ThreadID=23;_ThreadName=Thread-2440;|deployed with moduleid = *|#]
```

So eveything seems fine (note, the star/asterix * replaced the actual name here) but when looking into glassfish admin gui right after that => nothing changed so something did not work as mentioned in the log above but it seems no where logged what actually brokes up.